# Google Sheets – Calculate W-L Record when scoring a certain amount of points

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a pretty massive Google Sheet for my fantasy football league and have built out many pages to help keep track of various trends/statistics. Currently, I have formulas calculating W-L records for teams based on matchup scores, as well as COUNTIFS functions tallying the amount of times a team (person) has scored in a certain point range for a given week (i.e. Person A has scored between 75-100 points X amount of times).

What I'm trying to do now is combine the two into a page called "W-L by Points" where I want to calculate any person's Win-Loss Record when the score within a certain point range and/or their opponent scores within a certain point range.

I made a copy of my Sheet so everything is fair game because I have backup. [But I'm hoping someone can go check it out here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vxcQ0K4otOWn5N9zV8vHoimJOpyhlAZsZGHUto_Owww/edit#gid=818025268) and see what could be done. I'm happy if you just want to test a formula for one team/person and do it for just one season (page names like 2014SEASON, 2015SEASON, etc...) – I can then extrapolate the formula from there.

**EXAMPLE OF DESIRED RESULT**

If Person A throughout the fantasy football season has scored between 75-99.9 points any given week let's say 3 times:

**Week 3:** (Person A) 82.0 vs 79.5 (Opponent)

**Week 7:** (Person A) 78.3 vs 101.5 (Opponent)

**Week 11:** (Person A) 95.0 vs 92.5 (Opponent)

Then Person A's record when they scored between 75-99.9 points would be 2-1 (2 wins and 1 loss).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @player0 Sure! Just added an example in the original post. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(
 (QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A4:A16&"×"&{"W×0","L×0","W×75","L×75","W×100","L×100","W×120","L×120","W×150","L×150"}, IF({'2020SEASON'!A:A; '2019SEASON'!A:A}="",, {
 {'2020SEASON'!B:B; '2019SEASON'!B:B}&"×"&IF({'2020SEASON'!C:C; '2019SEASON'!C:C}>{'2020SEASON'!D:D; '2019SEASON'!D:D}, "W", "L")&"×"&VLOOKUP({'2020SEASON'!C:C; '2019SEASON'!C:C}, {0;75;100;120;150}, 1, 1), 
 {'2020SEASON'!E:E; '2019SEASON'!E:E}&"×"&IF({'2020SEASON'!C:C; '2019SEASON'!C:C}<{'2020SEASON'!D:D; '2019SEASON'!D:D}, "W", "L")&"×"&VLOOKUP({'2020SEASON'!D:D; '2019SEASON'!D:D}, {0;75;100;120;150}, 1, 1)})), "×")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col2 = 'W' group by Col1 pivot Col3")*1)-1&"-"&(1*
 QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A4:A16&"×"&{"W×0","L×0","W×75","L×75","W×100","L×100","W×120","L×120","W×150","L×150"}, IF({'2020SEASON'!A:A; '2019SEASON'!A:A}="",, {
 {'2020SEASON'!B:B; '2019SEASON'!B:B}&"×"&IF({'2020SEASON'!C:C; '2019SEASON'!C:C}>{'2020SEASON'!D:D; '2019SEASON'!D:D}, "W", "L")&"×"&VLOOKUP({'2020SEASON'!C:C; '2019SEASON'!C:C}, {0;75;100;120;150}, 1, 1), 
 {'2020SEASON'!E:E; '2019SEASON'!E:E}&"×"&IF({'2020SEASON'!C:C; '2019SEASON'!C:C}<{'2020SEASON'!D:D; '2019SEASON'!D:D}, "W", "L")&"×"&VLOOKUP({'2020SEASON'!D:D; '2019SEASON'!D:D}, {0;75;100;120;150}, 1, 1)})), "×")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col2 = 'L' group by Col1 pivot Col3"))-1, "offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! After a little bit of deciphering, I figured out how this equation was working and was able to extrapolate it out. I also added something to calculate win percentage as well. Perfect fix!.... Feel free to take a look at the most [up to date spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cgCNrQf0WvQNpoOhoODQ3Niaewkg_a6JlMsA7b5lgbo/edit#gid=818025268)

Answer (score 0):

Spread sheet in incredible. Dont know much about computer data, but if i wanted to use this template and import my own leagues data, I was just wondering if this was possible.
Do you have to manually update or are you sourcing the data from the fantasy site

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33200252)